# Is this an answer or comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

I reviewed some "Low Quality Posts" on SO and marked this answer as a "link only answer". In my opinion it is a good comment but not an answer!

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11039591

Answer or Comment?

Comment: Hurray Meta-effect!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That could be an answer, but it's a very low quality one. It might have a home as a comment.

My litmus test for these is simple: The first time I read an answer, I refuse to click any links. If the answer doesn't tell me anything useful, it's very low quality and should be deleted or improved.

You made the right call in your review.

Comment: It is plainly *not* an answer. There is zero information in it that answers the question.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I suspect you're right, but I tend to be careful about applying the NAA label - especially in topics I'm not well versed in.

Comment: NAA is often interpreted as "not an answer" (and who can blame you, its explained as such), but it means "Not an Attempt to Answer". Even something with zero information in it relating to the question asked can still be an attempt to answer, and thus does not full under the NAA flag. Its something to downvote instead. Somebody ranting, sharing the woes in their life or typing random characters, that's NAA material. (note: follow up to the comments, not the answer)